# Handling the tags that are available in the dropdown list options

Tags: javascript, html, razor, knockout.js, tags

I am trying to pull the data from the SQL server DB through API for the dropdown lists options like below, the API GetGInfo makes the call to DB and retrieves the data.

```
self.getGTypes = function (data, event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/REQ/GetGInfo',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            sNumber: self.sNumber()
        },
        success: function (response) {
            self.gTypes(response);
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error retrieving the record");
        }
    })
};
```

The UI

```
<select id="GType" name="GType" class="form-control" data-bind="
    options: gTypes,
    value: gType,
    optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
```

This works perfectly fine, but the data in the DB sometimes contains the html tags like  <sup>or  Lep<sup>ob</sup>.I am trying to understand if it is possible to show in UI like below</sup>

[image]

because in the dropdown I am just seeing like this Lepob.

[image]

How can I handle this

EDIT API that returns the data

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetGInfo(string sNumber)
{
    try
    {
    DSRepository dsr = new DSRepository();
    List<String> gTypeList = dsr.GetDDInfo(sNumber);
    if (gTypeList != null)
    {
         return Json(gTypeList);
    }
    else
        return Json("Not Applicable");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

GetDDInfo method

```
public List<string> GetDDInfo(string sNumber)
{
    using (JMPContainer jsContext = new JMPContainer())
    {
        try
        {
            return jsContext.vw_Plist.Where(x => x.sNumber== sNumber).Select(y => y.Gtype).Distinct().ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not going to work. An `option` element cannot contain any other tags.

If you really *must* have the superscript characters, I suppose you could convert the characters between the `<sup>` tags to their Unicode superscript versions.